# Does JavaScript arrow function have prototype?

Tags: javascript

I was just studying about prototype in Javascript. I read that, whenever we create a function in javascript, that function will have its prototype.

So, to test this I've created 3 functions, but all with different syntax like below:

//Function statement

```
function add1(){}
```

//Function expression

```
var add2=function(){}
```

//Arrow function

```
var add3=()=>{console.log('Javascript')};
```

After that I tried printing the prototype values of each function like below:

```
console.log(add1.prototype); //{constructor: ƒ}
console.log(add2.prototype); //{constructor: ƒ}
console.log(add3.prototype); //undefined
```

Why is arrow function prototype undefined?

Arrow function doesn't have any prototype?
OR
I am doing something wrong.

Please guide me.

Thanks
Dilip Solanki

Comment: You just needed to do a simple search.

Comment: "Why when I am trying to get the prototype of arrow function, @undefined is coming?"  ;) sry. couldn't resist